# (SQL) Sobre parênteses na cláusula WHERE

Tags: sql, lógica

Olá, não encontrei muitas informações em pesquisas que fiz sobre... mas estou com um problema atualmente que é o seguinte:

Eu tenho uma consulta com muitas condições simples, apenas sequencias de **and**. Mas hoje precisei incluir alguns **or**, e eis que a consulta simplesmente não consegue mais concluir, fica executando por minutos até parar por exceder o limite de memória do PostgresSQL ou algo do tipo.
Eis que então eu pensei em separar esses **or** dentro de um bloco, no caso, os botei dentro de parênteses e então a consulta rodou muito rapidamente e me trouxe um resultado sem erros.
Então eu resolvi fazer um teste com outra consulta, desta vez era bem mais simples e... quando eu botei os parênteses, a consulta agora não me trazia mais nada, mas se eu os removesse, ela executava como esperado.

Então eu comecei a me perguntar, o que realmente estava acontecendo e qual é o procedimento correto a fazer e como é que deve ser usado os parênteses na WHERE. Um obrigado desde já!

Exemplo da consulta que estou a utilizar sem parênteses:

```
nfe.id_empresa = 4 and 
nfe.ano = '2016' and
nfe.id_empresa = nfe_item.id_empresa and
nfe.ano = nfe_item.ano and
nfe.mes = nfe_item.mes and
nfe_item.cst_icms = '010' or 
nfe_item.cst_icms = '030' or
nfe_item.cst_icms = '060' or
nfe_item.cst_icms = '070' or
nfe_item.cst_icms = '110' ;
```

Agora com parênteses:

```
nfe.id_empresa = 4 and 
nfe.ano = '2016' and
nfe.id_empresa = nfe_item.id_empresa and
nfe.ano = nfe_item.ano and
nfe.mes = nfe_item.mes and
(
    nfe_item.cst_icms = '010' or 
    nfe_item.cst_icms = '030' or
    nfe_item.cst_icms = '060' or
    nfe_item.cst_icms = '070' or
    nfe_item.cst_icms = '110' 
);
```

Comment: A segunda query está correta, tem um `and` e todas as opções com `or` num parênteses (só um comentário, poderia usar `in` removendo os `or` e simplificando pra uma linha), agora tem q ver o número de registros na tabela (quantos registros tem a tabela?). O campo `cst_icms` deve ser `varchar`, estou certo?

Comment: Sem os parenteses, se nfe_item.cst_icms = '110' por exemplo, já vai retornar um valor independente de qualquer outro and que você colocou. Acredito que sua lógica exija os parênteses pra ficar correta. Provavelmente não está trazendo nada por outra falha de lógica.

Comment: Olá! Que bom então que eu estava fazendo corretamente. A tabela posssui 109 mil registros, é muita coisa. e Sim, é um VARCHAR a cst_icms!

Comment: Tente depois usar `IN` pra simplificar a sintaxe e não precisar do parênteses: `AND nfe_item.cst_icms IN ('010','030','060','070','110')`

Comment: Muito boa a dica, testei aqui e já estou utilizando. Obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assim como a multiplicação e a divisão têm precedência/prioridade sobre a adição e a subtração, o `AND` tem precedência/prioridade sobre o `OR`.

Ou seja, isso:

```
nfe.id_empresa = 4 and 
nfe.ano = '2016' and
nfe.id_empresa = nfe_item.id_empresa and
nfe.ano = nfe_item.ano and
nfe.mes = nfe_item.mes and
nfe_item.cst_icms = '010' or 
nfe_item.cst_icms = '030' or
nfe_item.cst_icms = '060' or
nfe_item.cst_icms = '070' or
nfe_item.cst_icms = '110' ;
```

É equivalente a isso:

```
(
    nfe.id_empresa = 4 and 
    nfe.ano = '2016' and
    nfe.id_empresa = nfe_item.id_empresa and
    nfe.ano = nfe_item.ano and
    nfe.mes = nfe_item.mes and
    nfe_item.cst_icms = '010'
) or 
nfe_item.cst_icms = '030' or
nfe_item.cst_icms = '060' or
nfe_item.cst_icms = '070' or
nfe_item.cst_icms = '110' ;
```

E não é isso o que você quer.

Veja mais sobre a precedência [**aqui**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE).

Na forma sem os parênteses, nos casos onde o `cst_icms` for `'030'`, `'060'`, `'070'` ou `'110'`, todos os registros serão trazidos independente dos demais campos (`id_empresa`, `ano`, `mes` ou qualquer coisa da tablea `nfe`). O resultado disso é um conjunto enorme de dados, e por isso demora um tempão.

Já na segunda forma com os parênteses nos `or`s, as cláusulas com `and` já terão filtrado um monte de resultados que seriam errados/indesejados antes de aplicar-se a filtragem pelo `cst_icms`.

Comment: Obrigado! Me esclareceu bastante.

Comment: Perfeito Victor. @RafaelAraujo, eu [fiz esse exemplo com dados e condições mais simples](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f74c7d/11) para fixar melhor a idéia. Além de tudo que já foi dito nas respostas, ainda que as precedências sejam observadas quando usar combinações de `OR` e `AND`, eu recomendaria que os parênteses fossem **sempre** incluídos: Evita esse problema e fica muito mais claro para outra pessoa interpretar a lógica do código.

Comment: Agradeço o conselho, é realmente muito bom pegar um código escrito de uma forma fácil para interpretar. Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

O parênteses faz com que o PostgreSQL trate todas as condições agrupadas como uma coisa só, por exemplo, na sua primeira consulta, como os OR estão fora do parênteses, então se qualquer `cst_icms` for igual a '030', '060', '070' ou '110', retornará essas linhas ignorando suas outras condições, pois um de seus `OR` foi atendido.

Agora na segunda query, em que você deixou suas condições OR agrupadas entre parenteses, para que uma linha seja retornada você precisa de cumprir todas as condições anteriores E uma das condições agrupadas por OR.

Espero ter sido claro até aqui.

Agora na questão de estourar o tempo de consulta do BD, o que pode estar acontecendo é que como na sua primeira consulta, sem os parenteses, você está retornando muitos resultados, o suficiente pro seu banco não conseguir exibir todos. Coloque um LIMIT 100, por exemplo, na sua primeira consulta e você verá que tem sim resultados, o problema é que eles são muitos.

Answer (score 1):

É só uma questão da [precedência dos operadores](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) onde "Um operador em níveis superiores é avaliado antes de um operador em um nível inferior".

Em outras palavras, o AND é processado antes do OR.

```
true and false and true or true or false
[   false    ]
[          false      ] 
[               true          ]
[                   true               ] = true
```

Mudando a precedência, usando os parênteses:

```
true and false and (true or (true or false))
                             [    true    ]
                    [      true           ] 
         [            false               ]
[                   false                 ] = false
```